# Какая часть речи слово "один"?

Tags: грамматика

*С тех пор мельчает немногочисленный русский Олимп и дольше всех держится лишь один – сомнительное наше страшилище лесов, леший, в крестьянском просторечии, лес.*

Какая часть речи *один?*

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Помогите определить, какой частью речи является слово " один" в приведённом предложении.

Comment: Уточните тему. Вас интересует только  "какая часть речи"?  Тогда нужно убрать фразу о морфологическом разборе. Дело в том, что разборы здесь не делаются, мы только можем проверить ваше решение.

Comment: @Sharon чё это "не делаются", а если мне нада?)

Comment: @Nektoid За ваши "у. е."... Что имеете ценного на обмен?

Comment: @Sharon имею вагон изобретательности) Например, я придумал, как склонять "у.е." по падежам: "я не имею у.ёв",  "я разорился на "у.ях". Согласитесь, изобретательно!

Comment: Кошмар, хотя в изобретательности вам не откажешь... А  это точно ваша шутка —  наверное, из Интернета списали.

Comment: @Sharon только что придумал) Но она, в общем-то, очевидная, так что и до меня, думаю, кто-то её использовал.

Comment: Жаль, а то можно было  бы авторство оформить...

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от контекста, слово "**один**" может выступать как местоимением, так и числительным. Вы можете дополнить Ваш вопрос, написав предложение, из контекста которого вырвано это слово?

UPD: Не увидел предложение, поэтому, прочитав его, можно отметить, что слово выступает в качестве **местоименного прилагательного**.

Comment: А в приведённом в пример предложении один это не существительное?

Comment: @Гуля, только сейчас увидел предложение, прошу прощения за невнимательность. Прочитав его, здесь, как мне кажется, слово "один" выступает местоименным прилагательным.

Comment: А какой вопрос можно поставить к нему от слова "держится"?

Comment: @Гуля так как в данном предложении слово "держится" выступает глаголом, то можно поставить вопрос: держится (который?) один. "Лишь" - частица, поэтому она никак не помешает задать вопрос.

Comment: @ven2ra "Прочитав его, здесь, как мне кажется..." — так говорить нельзя, это ошибка согласования, анаколуф. // Слово "держится" — глагол независимо от того, в каком предложении находится.

Comment: А я знаю, откуда предложение, ага! Это Леонов "Русский лес" https://litresp.ru/chitat/ru/Л/leonov-leonid/russkij-les/7  Читайте! Его еще и незаконно изменили :))